# Problema con Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema con Formik, la libreria de Reactjs, he hecho un registro con el, y creo que algo va mal en mi codigo, ya que no me deja enviar el formulario con el metodo post de axios, me sale este problema  "Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Object(...)(...).post is not a function" estoy aprendiendo Formik, no estoy muy familiarizado  con el, asi que por eso este error, aqui le dejo el codigo a ver si me pueden ayudar con el problema,   He semplificado algunas cosas, le he quitado la password y el email, pero el problema es el mismo no me deja enviar los datos, asi que otra vez, espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias!!!

```js
export function FormSingUp() {
  const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };
  
  
  
  const validate = (values) => {
    let errs = {};
    return errs;
  };
  
  const [stateUser, setStateUser] = useState(initialValues);
  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
await axios()
  .post("/user", stateUser)
  .then((res) => {
    setStateUser(res.values);
  })
  .catch();
  };
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validate={validate}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form className="SignUp">
          <div className="Name_LastName_Container">
            <Field
              name="name"
              id="nombre"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Nombre"
              className="Name_LastName"
            />
            <Field
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Apellido"
              className="Name_LastName"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="ButtonInput" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás tratando `axios` como una función, cuando en realidad es un Objeto, por eso el error.

Sólo cambia esto

```
axios().post(...)
```

por

```
axios.post(...)
```

Y listo :D

Comment: Podrías explicar tu respuesta?

Comment: Jjajajajaja vaya, que error de novato XD

Comment: Si me sirvio jajajja

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!